# Manipulate Queries before sending them to GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

We're using apollo-client and apollo-server-express to fetch data from a simple translation API.

That's the current schema:

```
type Query {
    translations(language: String!, key: String!): Translation!
}

type Translation {
    key: String!
    value: String!
}
```

And the resolver:

```
export default {
  Query: {
    translations (obj, args, context, info) {
      return fetchApi('/api/v1/translation', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(args)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

In the frontend application we've a React component that receives the translation key inside props and then executes the query against the GraphQL Server:

```
const translationQuery = gql`
query GetTranslations($language: String!, $key: String!) {
  translations(language: $language, key: $key) {
    value
    key
  }
}`
```

Right now this leads to GraphQL calls for EACH translation. What we need is to cumulate all translations and then perform ONE GraphQL query. Basically we'd like to use a query that accepts a list of keys but still use a dedicated translation component:

```
type Query {
    translations(language: String!, keys: [String!]!): Translation!
}

type Translation {
    key: String!
    value: String!
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what we need?

Here's a simplified version of how the translation component is implementend in the frontend application:
https://codesandbox.io/s/81n874zjp0

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there is a simple way

It is possible to pass an array as an argument to a query.

You can read more about ["GraphQL - Lists and Non-Null" here](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#lists-and-non-null)

In your query operation, instead of a single `key` defined as `$key: String!` you can pass in an array of non-nullable keys like so `$keys: [String!]!`

You also need to update your resolver function to handle the array of keys and return an either a single `Translation` or an array of `Translation`.

And lastly, make sure to update your schema.

If you are executing the API call only once and expect to get a single `Translation`, it should look something like this:

```
type Query {
    translations(language: String!, keys: [String!]!): Translation!
}

type Translation {
    key: String!
    value: String!
}
```

Comment: That's not possible for us. Each translation generates a new instance of a React component which executes the query (<Translation>SomeKey</Translation>). This means we can't adapt the query to send an array as we don't know anything about ALL the translations when executing the query. What we need is to manipulate/cumulate the translation queries before they get send to the GraphQL server or cumulate them on the GraphQL server before we fetch the API.

Comment: How about making the `Translation` component a controlled component that is managed by a `TranslationsContainer` component? Each Translation get its value via the props and updates `TranslationsContainer` with any change. That way you can get all the translation keys and values in one place and then use my proposed solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get it. When you have one controlled component you still have the same problems, don't you?  How do you know in the controlled component that all keys were passed before executing the query?

Comment: You didn't provide enough info to know for sure what will work for you. But one thing you can use is the query's skip option with a function that checks if your component already has all the keys based on the component's props. Read about it here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-skip

Comment: I setup a simplified version of how I implemented the translation component. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is impossible to understand from your code what exactly you mean by "the last one". It's too simplified. There's a simple answer to that, but that seems unrelated to your original question, so I assume I'm missing something.